# How to handle linker errors in C++/GNU toolchain?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, linker

Given a C++/GNU toolchain, what's a good method or tool or strategy to puzzle out linker errors?

Comment: what sort of linker errors ? and on Linux I assume ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at.. you need to fix your code or build/compiler settings.

Comment: @Hassan: I'm looking more for a general method, rather than a specific reccomendation.

Comment: GPL is a license, not a compiler. Do you mean C++ / GCC / FSF binutils?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gcc toolchain, I use:

- nm: to find the symbols in object files
- ld: to find how a library links
- c++filt: to find the C++ name of a symbol from its mangled name

Check [this](http://cpp-applied.info/IBM.Redbooks-Developing.and.Porting.C.and.CPP.Applications.on.AIX/7338final/LiB0047.html) for details.

Comment: nm -u for undefined symbols only

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you mean but if you are talking about cryptic linker symbols like:

mylib.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5CandyD2Ev

you can use c++filt to do the puzzling for you.

c++filt _ZN5CandyD2Ev

will return Candy::~Candy() so somehow Candy's destructor didn't get linked.

Answer (score 1):

Well the first thing would be RTFM. No, seriously, read the documentation.

If you don't want to do that, try a search on the error that comes up.

Here are a few other things to remember: "missing" symbols are often an indication that you haven't included the appropriate source or library; "missing" symbols are sometimes an indication that you're attempting to link a library created with a different mangling convention (or a different compiler); make sure that you have extern "C" where appropriate; declaring and defining aren't the same thing; if your compiler doesn't support "export" make sure your template code is available for when you instantiate objects.

Comment: If there were anything approaching documentation, I wouldn't be in this mess... Your advice does help, though.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the names of the symbols that are reported to be problematic.

- If there are missing symbols reported, find out in which source files or libraries those function/... should be defined in. Inspect the compilation/linker settings to find out why these files aren't compiled or linked.
- If there are multiply defined symbols the linker usually mentions which object files or libraries contain them. Look at those files/their sources to find out why the offending functions/... are included in both of them.